# Console output while running Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins.  I can see console output for jobs that have finished.  But, how do I view the console out for Jenkins jobs that are in progress?

Answer (score 6):

I think the question is how to see the output of the individual job, not the Jenkins system log. You can view console output of a job in progress by going to the page for that job in Jenkins and clicking on the colored ball for that job. The running build will have a flashing ball, while the completed jobs will not be flashing. In addition, you can click on the progress bar for a running job to see the console output.

[image]

Comment: Sadly enough, it stopped working a few versions ago, before 1.595. It was so convenient.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question very much depends on how you are running Jenkins. For example first example in the [starting Jenkins guide](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) demonstrates the following:

```
$ nohup java -jar jenkins.war > $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

Here you explicitly send the console output to a file. The problem is that there are lots of other ways to run Jenkins, so you are probabily better off configuring logging:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging

This will work if Jenkins is deployed inside a container like tomcat.

## Update

The system log is available from the "Manage Jenkins" -> "System Logs" screen. It contains most of what will appear on the console:

```
http://<hosthname>:<portnumber>/log/all
```

Answer (score 2):

You can view the console output for Jenkins jobs that are in progress by the following two steps below:

1. On Build History click on the progress bar. 
   [Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJrcI.png)
2. On the next window click on the Console Output to see the console output.
   [Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbofs.png)